# Background Needed for Research in Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, research

I was wondering how much background knowledge is needed to do research in some subfield of algebra. I am currently working on an application for a summer research program, and I need to choose a subfield of mathematics to research, but I'm not too sure whether research in algebra would be possible with only a read of Dummit and Foote and Artin's text on Algebra. Also, is linear algebra still a topic that is currently being researched? And finally, is ring theory something I could possibly handle with only background knowledge from the two texts listed above?

Comment: Research level mathematics is well beyond most upper year undergraduate/early graduate level texts. You'll get the foundation, but you won't have nearly enough background to do research.

Comment: Are you applying to an REU? What program specifically? I did an REU this summer so if you want more information about that, I can help you. Not too sure about your other quesitons.

Comment: I'm currently in high school. I'm applying to RSI.